# Implement custom "ValidateUser" in MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, code-first

I am implementing a custom MembershipProvider and I am trying to get the `ValidateUser` method to validate against my `Profiles` table in SQL Server. This table has columns called `UserName` and `Password`.

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    ??? what to do here???
}
```

FYI, I am using MVC3 & EF 4.1 Code First.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using EF 4.1, you will have some kind of a `DbContext` object that contains the `DbSet` for your `Profiles` table - right?

So in that case, use this:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using(DbContext yourCtx = new DbContext())
    {
        // from your "Profiles" DbSet, retrieve that single entry which
        // matches the username/password being passed in

        var profile = (from p in yourCtx.Profiles
                      where p.UserName == username && p.Password == password
                      select p).SingleOrDefault();

        // if that query returns a "Profile" (is != null), then your
        // username/password combo is valid - otherwise, it's not valid
        return (profile != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent :) however VS is not liking the line:

using(DbContext yourCtx = new DbContext())

...says 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DbContext()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Thanks Paul

Comment: @Paul Brown: you need to replace `DbContext` with your concrete database context (I don't know what it's called - it should be a class deriving from `DbContext`)

Comment: @ marc_s - Excellent, got that sorted. Now one last thing..."var profile"   is giving "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable"

any ideas?

thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Paul Brown: oh, sorry - my bad - the `.SingleOrDefault()` is a method and thus needs a pair of parens at the end...